# jQuery allow only positive or negative numbers (without decimals)

Tags: jquery

How can I change my code to also accept negative numbers, but without decimals? Right now it only accepts positive numbers...

```js
  $("#numbers").keydown(function (e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8]) !== -1 ||
      (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
      (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
        return;
    }
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numbers" />
```

Comment: `<input type="number" />` ...?

Comment: It would also accept decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. As Rory McCrossan mentions:

```
<input type="number" />
```

works in case you submit it in some way.
Try it here: [inputnumbers](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FC5AF9NBNAZW)

In your case, it looks like you don't want the user to be able to decimal numbers at all.

One solution is to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : (event.charCode == 45 || event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)" />
```

Try it: [tryme](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FC5BYB3448VH)

Comment: I don't want the user to be able to input decimal numbers, but only negative and positive numbers...can you please add a fiddle? I can't get your solution working

Answer (score 0):

You can round the input number using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

Also, if you want to discard decimals numbers, you can do something like that:

```
var raw = $(input).val();
var rounded = parseInt(raw);
if (rounded < raw) {
   // discard logic..
}
```